# Vue, how to assign unique v-model parameter in loop

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to assign different and unique parameter in loop to each input tag (v-model)

I tried the code below

```
<template>
<div v-for="item in lst" key="item">
 <input :v-model="item"> </input>
</div>
</template>
<script setup>
var lst = ['first_vmodel_value','second_vmodel_value']

</script>
```

By doing this I want to access to each input tag v-model value. The example above, there are only two item value but actually much more value exists.

- The code above is not working. I want to assign unique v-model value to each input tag.
  The intent of the code is to access v-model value using lst item, for example first_vmodel_value or second_vmodel_value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use ref/reactive Object - and it's `v-model` not `:v-model`

The content of your `lst` would be used to create properties in `models` (it's an arbitrary name)

```
<script setup>
import {reactive} from "vue";
var lst = ['first_vmodel_value','second_vmodel_value']
const models = reactive({});
</script>

<template>
  <div v-for="item in lst" key="item">
    <input v-model="models[item]"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Or possibly it's better like this

```
<script setup>
import {reactive} from "vue";
const models = reactive({
  first_vmodel_value: '',
  second_vmodel_value: '',
});
</script>

<template>
  <div v-for="item in models" key="item">
    <input v-model="item"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: wow JaromandaX,  I try this, and It worked perfectly! thank you for answering and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of refs.

```
<template>
<div v-for="item in lst">
 <input v-model="item.value">
</div>
</template>
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
const lst = ['first_vmodel_value','second_vmodel_value'].map(k => ref(k));
</script>
```

Alternatively, we can use one deeply reactive array and bind to each index.

According to the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html):

> If an object is assigned as a ref's value, the object is made deeply reactive with reactive().

```
<template>
<div v-for="(_, index) in lst">
 <input v-model="lst[index]">
</div>
</template>
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
const lst = ref(['first_vmodel_value','second_vmodel_value']);
</script>
```

Comment: This is also really useful answer! thank you for answering Unmitigated, I will definetly  check 'this answer is useful' later, my reputation is only 9 now. Have a nice day :)

Comment: should `v-model="item.value"` just be `v-model="item"`?